# CSS3 - Translate to plain english

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can someone please translate the following CSS to plain English for me.

```
#menu ul li:first-child > a:after
```

Comment: http://flukeout.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#menu ul li:first-child > a:after
```

Select `:after` pseudo element inside `a` element, the `a` element should be the direct child of `li` and the `li` should be the first child of any `ul` inside any element which have `#menu` id

Answer (score 1):

Apply the defined styles to the `:after` pseudo element of *all* `a` elements that are *children* of the *first* `li` element inside of *all* `ul` elements that are inside an element with id `menu`.

Or

> Selects any content placed after an a element that is a child of a li
>   element that is a first child that is a descendant of an ul element
>   that is a descendant of any element with an id attribute that equals
>   menu.

via [SelectOracle](http://gallery.theopalgroup.com/selectoracle/)

Comment: What is :after pseudo element?

Comment: The CSS ::after pseudo-element matches a virtual last child of the selected element. It is typically used to add cosmetic content to an element by using the content CSS property. This element is inline by default.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter

Comment: @JonP No Jon, Google is not broken. However, sometimes it makes more sense if you hear it from an expert in plain English rather than read techy documentation. Hope you can relate.

Answer (score 1):

> `#menu ul li:first-child > a:after`

*means:*

Target the [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter) [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pseudo-elements) (technically, `::after`)...

which is associated with an anchor element (`a`)...

that is a child of a list item (`li`)...

which is first on the list among siblings (`:first-child`).

The `li` must be a descendant (but not necessarily a child) of an unordered list (`ul`)...

which itself is a descendant of an element with the `id` value of `menu`.